# Getting Empty String from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

```
   for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        kn = ds.child("keyname").getValue().toString();
                        position1 = ds.child("position").getValue().toString();
                        value=ds.child(kn).getValue().toString();
                      }
```

As you can see the value of keyname becomes is itself a key for other field. First I intend to fetch the value of keyname then with that keyname I intend to fetch the other value. I am able to get the value against keyname and that i store in kn which is a String type variable. but when i try to get the other value with the help of kn... i get an empty string. Can anyone help me understand this situation.

Comment: if I understood correctly you want value like `https://firebas` for key ` How to send form data to a servelet` but for that key, you are getting empty value?

Comment: yes exactly, i am getting an empty string.

Comment: you are getting correct values for `kn` and `position1`? only empty for `value`?

Comment: yes i m getting correct values for kn and position1

Comment: Can you try one thing create a key with no space and try the same code and see with that works

Comment: nope it doesn't work.

Comment: That seems unexpected. Can you show the full snippet of code, including how you load the data, and how you use it?

Comment: @FaisalNazir Can you show the full snippet of code as requested by Frank

Comment: I got rid of this method and created separate methods to get each value from firebase. that worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Just curious to see what exactly you did there which fixed it, can you share your snippet of your new method.